# JMeter HTML Report - Specify different APDEX thresholds per page/request

Tags: jmeter

Our webapp has several very long running requests where we show the user a progress bar. It doesn't makes sense to use the same APDEX values for these requests.

The APDEX table includes columns showing the thresholds for each page, which leads me to believe there should be a way to do it. Why include them per page instead of just saying once at the top.

I would also be totally happy just excluding these pages from the APDEX completely.

I can't find anything about exlcuding or customizing APDEX in the [docs](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot customize thresholds per transaction, it is a enhancement request that has not yet been implemented:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60112

Edit on 14/04/2017:

- since JMeter 3.2, it is now possible to customize thresholds per transaction

  ```
     jmeter.reportgenerator.apdex_satisfied_threshold=500

     jmeter.reportgenerator.apdex_tolerated_threshold=1500

   jmeter.reportgenerator.apdex_per_transaction=sample(\\d+):1000|2000;\
  ```

  sampleA:3000|4000;\
  scenarioB:5000|6000

You can cutomize the template that contain the index, it's a freemarker template located in:

- bin/report-template/index.html.fmkr

I suggest you copy existing folder, modify the file and reference it with property in user.properties file:

> jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.property.template_dir=path to the copied and modified template folder

An even nicer idea would be to implement the enhancement and contribute it back to JMeter.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with JMeter 3.3 like this

```
jmeter.reportgenerator.apdex_per_transaction=sample(\\d+):1000|2000;\
    sampleA:3000|4000;\
    scenarioB:5000|6000
```

Documentation is here: https://jmeter.apache.org/changes_history.html

JMeter 3.2 had a bug, which makes this feature unusable: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61292